# Xcode hiding buttons

Tags: ios, button

I'm curious to know is there a way to edit what happens at a app startup to hide buttons? I can hide them when the app is running but I want some buttons hidden when the app starts up and displayed later on after me touching one of my displayed buttons, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Define them as hidden in the XIB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### In code

`UIView` has a `hidden` property. You can toggle it to hide/show as you want in code, for example:

```
myView.hidden = YES; // YES/NO
```

You'll want to do this anywhere after `-viewDidLoad`

### Interface Builder

In the inspector, once you've selected the view you want to hide, you should see something like this (look in the View > Drawing options - at the bottom).

It's the hidden property you want to check here... You'll want to make an outlet to your code so you can unhide this later on...

[image]

Comment: Lucky - you have a Retina machine!

Comment: Yea I was going to comment on that, it's huge ! It's really nice, the retina simulator is life size, so no need to scale out to see everything. But the normal simulator is quite blurry...

Answer (score 1):

You could initially set your buttons hidden via the `Attribute Inspector`.
There's a check box down there `View -> Drawing -> Hidden` to hide the button.

Then you coud to set your buttons visible in the touch action of another visible button like following:

```
#import "HBOSViewController.h"

@interface HBOSViewController ()
// your buttons outlets here
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *topButton1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *topButton;

@end

@implementation HBOSViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// The action of the visible button to make your hidden button visible.
- (IBAction)showButton:(id)sender {
    if (self.topButton) {
        self.topButton.hidden=NO;
    }
    if (self.topButton1) {
        self.topButton1.hidden=NO;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean on a view which you created using a XIB (Interface Builder) file. If that's the case, simply set the hidden flag on any buttons you want to be initially hidden.

Comment: I've tried finding some kind of hidden option or flag, I cannot seem to locate it though, apart from a button that hides the drawing but I'm still left with my text. Could you possibly direct me to where it is? Apologies for this, still quite new to it all heh. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: It looks like you're expecting your view to hide in the interface builder? It won't... It will just alpha out a little. See my screenshot of the pane you'll need to check the hidden property.

Answer (score 0):

In `-viewDidLoad` just add something like `yourButton.hidden = YES;`

Comment: Watch out, for consistency, I really strongly suggest you stick with YES/NO and not true/false when writing Objective-C

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm pretty new to Objective C and Stackoverflow.